# Command to check if connection to a remote system is active using mstsc

Tags: java, networking, command-prompt

How do I check using command prompt or programatically if my system is connected to a remote system or not using mstsc.

Comment: you mean like "ping" ?

Comment: No. I am using mstsc to connect to a remote system D1DTC712. Now how do I know programatically if I am connected to that remote system or not.

Comment: Anybody please answer